ros2 control spawner not working : [spawner-6] [INFO]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
Hello my name is Chanhui Lee.
I made robot arm, and I want to control this robot arm with ros2 control and moveit2.
https://youtu.be/cu4kgPsb-7E?si=ocTe_xz_FJuSSxTK
I made robot arm package like bottom github repository.
https://github.com/chanhuirobot/rh_plus_7_axis_robot_arm
and if I launch bringup.launch.py it shows ros2 control spawner error
and then it stops with error
this is my error log... I googled, and found out foxy does not have this error, but humble have this problem, and some people talked about my robot description(urdf files..)
how can i fix this problem..?

this is log
chanhuirobot@chanhuirobot-ROG-Strix-G614JV:~$ ros2 launch rh_plus_7_axis_robot_arm_moveit_config bringup.launch.py 
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/chanhuirobot/.ros/log/2024-08-20-20-58-33-812483-chanhuirobot-ROG-Strix-G614JV-33147
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-1]: process started with pid [33153]
[INFO] [ros2_control_node-2]: process started with pid [33155]
[INFO] [move_group-3]: process started with pid [33157]
[INFO] [rviz2-4]: process started with pid [33159]
[INFO] [spawner-5]: process started with pid [33161]
[INFO] [spawner-6]: process started with pid [33163]
[INFO] [spawner-7]: process started with pid [33165]
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Subscribing to '~/robot_description' topic for robot description file.
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: update rate is 50 Hz
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: RT kernel is recommended for better performance
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO]: got segment base_link
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO]: got segment gripper_base
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO]: got segment gripper_hand_left
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO]: got segment gripper_hand_right
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO]: got segment link1
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO]: got segment link2
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO]: got segment link3
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO]: got segment link4
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO]: got segment link5
[rviz2-4] Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
[move_group-3] [INFO]: Loaded robot model in 0.000857192 seconds
[move_group-3] [INFO]: Loading robot model 'rh_plus_7_axis_robot_arm'...
[rviz2-4] [INFO]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[rviz2-4] [INFO]: OpenGl version: 4.6 (GLSL 4.6)
[rviz2-4] [INFO]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[rviz2-4] Warning: class_loader.impl: SEVERE WARNING!!! A namespace collision has occurred with plugin factory for class rviz_default_plugins::displays::InteractiveMarkerDisplay. New factory will OVERWRITE existing one. This situation occurs when libraries containing plugins are directly linked against an executable (the one running right now generating this message). Please separate plugins out into their own library or just don't link against the library and use either class_loader::ClassLoader/MultiLibraryClassLoader to open.
[rviz2-4]          at line 253 in /opt/ros/humble/include/class_loader/class_loader/class_loader_core.hpp
[move_group-3] [INFO]: Publishing maintained planning scene on 'monitored_planning_scene'
[move_group-3] [INFO]: Listening to 'joint_states' for joint states
[move_group-3] [INFO]: Listening to joint states on topic 'joint_states'
[move_group-3] [INFO]: Listening to '/attached_collision_object' for attached collision objects
[move_group-3] [INFO]: Starting planning scene monitor
[move_group-3] [INFO]: Listening to '/planning_scene'
[move_group-3] [INFO]: Starting world geometry update monitor for collision objects, attached objects, octomap updates.
[move_group-3] [INFO]: Listening to 'collision_object'
[move_group-3] [INFO]: Listening to 'planning_scene_world' for planning scene world geometry
[move_group-3] [WARN]: Resolution not specified for Octomap. Assuming resolution = 0.1 instead
[move_group-3] [ERROR]: No 3D sensor plugin(s) defined for octomap updates
[move_group-3] [INFO]: Loading planning pipeline 'ompl'
[spawner-6] [INFO]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
[move_group-3] [INFO]: Using planning interface 'OMPL'
[move_group-3] [INFO]: Param 'ompl.path_tolerance' was not set. Using default value: 0.100000
[move_group-3] [INFO]: Param 'ompl.resample_dt' was not set. Using default value: 0.100000
[move_group-3] [INFO]: Param 'ompl.min_angle_change' was not set. Using default value: 0.001000
[move_group-3] [INFO]: Param 'ompl.default_workspace_bounds' was not set. Using default value: 10.000000
[move_group-3] [INFO]: Param 'ompl.start_state_max_bounds_error' was set to 0.100000
[move_group-3] [INFO]: Param 'ompl.start_state_max_dt' was not set. Using default value: 0.500000
[move_group-3] [INFO]: Param 'ompl.start_state_max_dt' was not set. Using default value: 0.500000
[move_group-3] [INFO]: Param 'ompl.jiggle_fraction' was not set. Using default value: 0.020000
[move_group-3] [INFO]: Param 'ompl.max_sampling_attempts' was not set. Using default value: 100
[move_group-3] [INFO]: Using planning request adapter 'Add Time Optimal Parameterization'
[move_group-3] [INFO]: Using planning request adapter 'Resolve constraint frames to robot links'
[move_group-3] [INFO]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Workspace Bounds'
[move_group-3] [INFO]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Start State Bounds'
[move_group-3] [INFO]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Start State In Collision'
[move_group-3] [INFO]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Start State Path Constraints'
[spawner-5] [INFO]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
[move_group-3] [INFO]: Added FollowJointTrajectory controller for arm_controller
[move_group-3] [INFO]: Max effort set to 0.0
[move_group-3] [INFO]: Added GripperCommand controller for hand_controller
[move_group-3] [INFO]: Returned 2 controllers in list
[move_group-3] [INFO]: Returned 2 controllers in list
[move_group-3] [INFO]: Trajectory execution is not managing controllers
[move_group-3] [INFO]: MoveGroup debug mode is ON
[move_group-3] [INFO]: 
[move_group-3] 
[move_group-3] ********************************************************
[move_group-3] * MoveGroup using: 
[move_group-3] *     - ApplyPlanningSceneService
[move_group-3] *     - ClearOctomapService
[move_group-3] *     - CartesianPathService
[move_group-3] *     - ExecuteTrajectoryAction
[move_group-3] *     - GetPlanningSceneService
[move_group-3] *     - KinematicsService
[move_group-3] *     - MoveAction
[move_group-3] *     - MotionPlanService
[move_group-3] *     - QueryPlannersService
[move_group-3] *     - StateValidationService
[move_group-3] ********************************************************
[move_group-3] 
[move_group-3] [INFO]: MoveGroup context using planning plugin ompl_interface/OMPLPlanner
[move_group-3] [INFO]: MoveGroup context initialization complete
[spawner-7] [INFO]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
[rviz2-4] [ERROR]: Action server: /recognize_objects not available
[rviz2-4] [INFO]: MoveGroup namespace changed: / -> . Reloading params.
[rviz2-4] [INFO]: Loaded robot model in 0.00158907 seconds
[rviz2-4] [INFO]: Loading robot model 'rh_plus_7_axis_robot_arm'...
[spawner-6] [INFO]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
[spawner-5] [INFO]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
[spawner-7] [INFO]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
[rviz2-4] [INFO]: Starting planning scene monitor
[rviz2-4] [INFO]: Listening to '/monitored_planning_scene'
[rviz2-4] [INFO]: Connected on namespace: /rviz_moveit_motion_planning_display/robot_interaction_interactive_marker_topic
[rviz2-4] [INFO]: Sending request for interactive markers
[rviz2-4] [INFO]: group arm
[rviz2-4] [INFO]: Constructing new MoveGroup connection for group 'arm' in namespace ''
[rviz2-4] [INFO]: Ready to take commands for planning group arm.
[rviz2-4] [INFO]: group arm
[rviz2-4] [INFO]: Service response received for initialization
[spawner-6] [INFO]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
[spawner-5] [INFO]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
[spawner-7] [INFO]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
[spawner-6] [INFO]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
[spawner-5] [INFO]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
[spawner-7] [INFO]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
[spawner-6] [ERROR]: Controller manager not available
[spawner-5] [ERROR]: Controller manager not available
[spawner-7] [ERROR]: Controller manager not available
[ERROR] [spawner-6]: process has died [pid 33163, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/spawner arm_controller --controller-manager /controller_manager --ros-args -r __node:=arm_controller_node --params-file /tmp/launch_params_02p6wesh'].
[ERROR] [spawner-5]: process has died [pid 33161, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/spawner joint_state_broadcaster --controller-manager /controller_manager --ros-args -r __node:=joint_state_broadcaster_node --params-file /tmp/launch_params_6kortwsu'].
[ERROR] [spawner-7]: process has died [pid 33165, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/spawner hand_controller --controller-manager /controller_manager --ros-args -r __node:=hand_controller_node --params-file /tmp/launch_params_zfd_s0vx'].

this is launch file
#!/usr/bin/env -S ros2 launch
"""Configure and setup move group for planning with MoveIt 2"""

from os import path
from typing import List

import yaml
import launch_ros.descriptions
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument
from launch.conditions import IfCondition
from launch.substitutions import (
    Command,
    FindExecutable,
    LaunchConfiguration,
    PathJoinSubstitution,
    PythonExpression
)
from launch_ros.actions import Node
from launch_ros.substitutions import FindPackageShare


def generate_launch_description():

    # Declare all launch arguments
    declared_arguments = generate_declared_arguments()

    # Get substitution for all arguments
    description_package = LaunchConfiguration("description_package")
    description_filepath = LaunchConfiguration("description_filepath")
    moveit_config_package = "rh_plus_7_axis_robot_arm_moveit_config"
    name = LaunchConfiguration("name")
    prefix = LaunchConfiguration("prefix")
    collision = LaunchConfiguration("collision")
    safety_limits = LaunchConfiguration("safety_limits")
    safety_position_margin = LaunchConfiguration("safety_position_margin")
    safety_k_position = LaunchConfiguration("safety_k_position")
    safety_k_velocity = LaunchConfiguration("safety_k_velocity")
    ros2_control = LaunchConfiguration("ros2_control")
    ros2_control_plugin = LaunchConfiguration("ros2_control_plugin")
    gazebo_preserve_fixed_joint = LaunchConfiguration("gazebo_preserve_fixed_joint")
    enable_rviz = LaunchConfiguration("enable_rviz")
    rviz_config = LaunchConfiguration("rviz_config")
    use_sim_time = LaunchConfiguration("use_sim_time")
    log_level = LaunchConfiguration("log_level")

    # URDF
    _robot_description_xml = Command(
        [
            PathJoinSubstitution([FindExecutable(name="xacro")]),
            " ",
            PathJoinSubstitution(
                [FindPackageShare(moveit_config_package), description_filepath]
            ),
            " ",
            "name:=",
            name,
            " ",
            "prefix:=",
            prefix,
            " ",
            "collision:=",
            collision,
            " ",
            "safety_limits:=",
            safety_limits,
            " ",
            "safety_position_margin:=",
            safety_position_margin,
            " ",
            "safety_k_position:=",
            safety_k_position,
            " ",
            "safety_k_velocity:=",
            safety_k_velocity,
            " ",
            "ros2_control:=",
            ros2_control,
            " ",
            "ros2_control_plugin:=",
            ros2_control_plugin,
            " ",
            "gazebo_preserve_fixed_joint:=",
            gazebo_preserve_fixed_joint,
        ]
    )
    robot_description = {"robot_description": _robot_description_xml}

    # SRDF
    _robot_description_semantic_xml = Command(
        [
            PathJoinSubstitution([FindExecutable(name="xacro")]),
            " ",
            PathJoinSubstitution(
                [FindPackageShare(moveit_config_package), "config/rh_plus_7_axis_robot_arm.srdf"]
            ),
            " ",
            "name:=",
            name,
            " ",
            "prefix:=",
            prefix,
            " ",
        ]
    )

    robot_description_semantic = {
        "robot_description_semantic": _robot_description_semantic_xml
    }

    # Kinematics
    kinematics = load_yaml(
        moveit_config_package, path.join("config", "kinematics.yaml")
    )

    # Joint limits
    joint_limits = {
        "robot_description_planning": load_yaml(
            moveit_config_package, path.join("config", "joint_limits.yaml")
        )
    }

    # Planning pipeline
    planning_pipeline = {
        "planning_pipelines": ["ompl"],
        "default_planning_pipeline": "ompl",
        "ompl": {
            "planning_plugin": "ompl_interface/OMPLPlanner",
            "request_adapters": "default_planner_request_adapters/AddTimeOptimalParameterization default_planner_request_adapters/ResolveConstraintFrames default_planner_request_adapters/FixWorkspaceBounds default_planner_request_adapters/FixStartStateBounds default_planner_request_adapters/FixStartStateCollision default_planner_request_adapters/FixStartStatePathConstraints",
            "start_state_max_bounds_error": 0.1,
        },
    }
    _ompl_yaml = load_yaml(
        moveit_config_package, path.join("config", "ompl_planning.yaml")
    )
    planning_pipeline["ompl"].update(_ompl_yaml)

    # Planning scene
    planning_scene_monitor_parameters = {
        "publish_planning_scene": True,
        "publish_geometry_updates": True,
        "publish_state_updates": True,
        "publish_transforms_updates": True,
    }

    # MoveIt controller manager
    moveit_controller_manager_yaml = load_yaml(
        moveit_config_package, path.join("config", "moveit_controllers.yaml")
    )
    moveit_controller_manager = {
        "moveit_controller_manager": "moveit_simple_controller_manager/MoveItSimpleControllerManager",
        "moveit_simple_controller_manager": moveit_controller_manager_yaml,
    }

    # Trajectory execution
    trajectory_execution = {
        "allow_trajectory_execution": True,
        "moveit_manage_controllers": False,
        "trajectory_execution.allowed_execution_duration_scaling": 1.2,
        "trajectory_execution.allowed_goal_duration_margin": 0.5,
        "trajectory_execution.allowed_start_tolerance": 0.01,
    }

    # Controller parameters
    declared_arguments.append(
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            "__controller_parameters_basename",
            default_value=["ros2_controllers.yaml"]
        )
    )

    controller_parameters = PathJoinSubstitution(
        [
            FindPackageShare(moveit_config_package),
            "config",
            LaunchConfiguration("__controller_parameters_basename"),
        ]
    )

    # List of nodes to be launched
    nodes = [
        # robot_state_publisher
        Node(
            package="robot_state_publisher",
            executable="robot_state_publisher",
            output="log",
            # arguments=["--ros-args", "--log-level", log_level],
            parameters=[
                robot_description,
                {
                    "publish_frequency": 50.0,
                    "frame_prefix": "",
                    "use_sim_time": use_sim_time,
                },
            ],
        ),
        Node(
            package="controller_manager",
            executable="ros2_control_node",
            output="log",
            # arguments=["--ros-args", "--log-level", log_level],
            parameters=[
                controller_parameters,
                {"use_sim_time": use_sim_time},
            ],
        ),
        Node(
            package="moveit_ros_move_group",
            executable="move_group",
            output="log",
            # arguments=["--ros-args", "--log-level", log_level],
            parameters=[
                robot_description,
                robot_description_semantic,
                kinematics,
                joint_limits,
                planning_pipeline,
                trajectory_execution,
                planning_scene_monitor_parameters,
                moveit_controller_manager,
                {"use_sim_time": use_sim_time},
            ]
        ),
        # rviz2
        Node(
            package="rviz2",
            executable="rviz2",
            output="log",
            arguments=[
                "--display-config",
                rviz_config,
                # "--ros-args",
                # "--log-level",
                # log_level,
            ],
            parameters=[
                robot_description,
                robot_description_semantic,
                kinematics,
                planning_pipeline,
                joint_limits,
                {"use_sim_time": use_sim_time},
            ],
            condition=IfCondition(enable_rviz),
        ),
    ]

    # Add nodes for loading controllers
    for controller in ["joint_state_broadcaster", "arm_controller", "hand_controller"]:
        nodes.append(
            Node(
                package="controller_manager",
                executable="spawner",
                name = controller + '_node',
                output="log",
                arguments=[controller, "--controller-manager", "/controller_manager"],
                parameters=[{"use_sim_time": use_sim_time}],
             ),
        )

    return LaunchDescription(declared_arguments + nodes)

def load_yaml(package_name: str, file_path: str):
    """
    Load yaml configuration based on package name and file path relative to its share.
    """

    package_path = get_package_share_directory(package_name)
    absolute_file_path = path.join(package_path, file_path)
    return parse_yaml(absolute_file_path)


def parse_yaml(absolute_file_path: str):
    """
    Parse yaml from file, given its absolute file path.
    """

    try:
        with open(absolute_file_path, "r") as file:
            return yaml.safe_load(file)
    except EnvironmentError:
        return None


def generate_declared_arguments() -> List[DeclareLaunchArgument]:
    """
    Generate list of all launch arguments that are declared for this launch script.
    """

    return [
        # Locations of robot resources
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            "description_package",
            default_value="rh_plus_7_axis_robot_arm_description",
            description="Custom package with robot description.",
        ),
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            "description_filepath",
            default_value="config/rh_plus_7_axis_robot_arm.urdf.xacro",
            description="Path to xacro or URDF description of the robot, relative to share of `description_package`.",
        ),
        # Naming of the robot
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            "name",
            default_value="rh_plus_7_axis_robot_arm",
            description="Name of the robot.",
        ),
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            "prefix",
            default_value="",
            description="Prefix for all robot entities. If modified, then joint names in the configuration of controllers must also be updated.",
        ),
        # Collision geometry
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            "collision",
            default_value="true",
            description="Flag to enable collision geometry for manipulator's arm.",
        ),
        # Safety controller
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            "safety_limits",
            default_value="true",
            description="Flag to enable safety limits controllers on manipulator joints.",
        ),
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            "safety_position_margin",
            default_value="0.15",
            description="Lower and upper margin for position limits of all safety controllers.",
        ),
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            "safety_k_position",
            default_value="100.0",
            description="Parametric k-position factor of all safety controllers.",
        ),
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            "safety_k_velocity",
            default_value="40.0",
            description="Parametric k-velocity factor of all safety controllers.",
        ),
        # ROS 2 control
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            "ros2_control",
            default_value="true",
            description="Flag to enable ros2 controllers for manipulator.",
        ),
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            "ros2_control_plugin",
            default_value="fake",
            description="The ros2_control plugin that should be loaded for the manipulator ('fake', 'ign', 'real' or custom).",
        ),
        # Gazebo
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            "gazebo_preserve_fixed_joint",
            default_value="false",
            description="Flag to preserve fixed joints and prevent lumping when generating SDF for Gazebo.",
        ),
        # Miscellaneous
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            "enable_rviz", default_value="true", description="Flag to enable RViz2."
        ),
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            "rviz_config",
            default_value=path.join(
                get_package_share_directory("rh_plus_7_axis_robot_arm_moveit_config"),
                "rviz",
                "moveit.rviz",
            ),
            description="Path to configuration for RViz2.",
        ),
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            "use_sim_time",
            default_value="false",
            description="If true, use simulated clock.",
        ),
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            "log_level",
            default_value="warn",
            description="The level of logging that is applied to all ROS 2 nodes launched by this script.",
        ),
    ]


The controller_manager inside ros2_control_node waits for the robot description, but on the wrong topic. Add the remapping like we have in the humble version of our demos here.

oh thanks for your answer! :)
hum... unfortunately, ros2_control_node died after remapping... before change, it did not die, and shows
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Subscribing to '~/robot_description' topic for robot description file.

it dies without any error message?

at least it should report
 [ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Subscribing to '/robot_description' topic before

i solved this problem by your help! details are in second answer.

i found out your solution is correct! i have issue between ros2_controller.yaml and urdf's ros2_control tag. After checking my config file and urdf file, without robot_description parameter, it works!

great that you found it!

Solution : add robot_description parameter at "ros2_control_node"
even if ros2_control_node says this method is deprecated.

also this problem is related with <ros2_control> tag in robot's description packages urdf file. if ros2_control.yaml, moveit_controller.yaml, urdf does not match, spawner dies...
Thanks for Christoph Froehlich! Even though remapping didn't work(i don't know why... i'll put image on the bottom.), you helped me to doubt ros2_control_node, and this helped me to solve problem.
Thanks from Chanhui
p.s.

before remapping


shows [ros2_control_node-2] [INFO]: Subscribing to '~/robot_description' topic for robot description file.
but spawner dies


after remapping


ros2_control_node dies like image


solved problem by adding robot_description file at ros2_control_node.



Some number parsed from the URDF with stod() failed. Where is the number of joints output coming from?
fyi: Your solution will work on humble but not in future distros.

i found out your solution is correct! i have issue between ros2_controller.yaml and urdf's ros2_control tag. After checking my config file and urdf file, without robot_description parameter, it works!
